# I am using crispy form to render the form. In my form there is one multiple checkbox field.I want to show some options as selected.How to do that

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am using django-crispy-forms. One of the form field is multiple choice checkbox. In this checkbox i wanted to show some options as checked. How to do that.

choices are declared as:-

documents_req = (
('1', 'TC'),
('2', 'Marksheet'),
('3', 'Char Cert'),
('4', 'Caste Cert')
)

Form is created as following:-
class AddStudentForm(forms.Form):
....
....
documents_required =
forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=documents_req,required=False,
widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
def **init**(self, *args, **kwargs):
super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)
self.helper = FormHelper()
self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
self.helper.form_tag = False
self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
self.helper.layout = Layout(
Div(
Div('email', css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0
border border-secondary'),
Div('password', css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0
border border-secondary'),
Div('address_1', css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0
border border-secondary'),
css_class='form-row'),
Div(
Div('address_2', css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0
border border-secondary'),
Div('city', css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0
border border-secondary'),
Div('state', css_class='form-group col-sm-4 mb-0
border border-secondary'),
css_class='form-row'),
Div(

```
             Div(InlineCheckboxes('documents_required'),css_class='form-group col-sm-6 mb-0 border border-secondary'),
            Div('zip_code', css_class='form-group col-sm-3 mb-0 border border-secondary'),
            Div('check_me_out', css_class='form-group col-sm-3 mb-0 border border-secondary'),
            css_class='form-row')

    )
```

It is perfectly showing the checkboxes. But I wanted some choices let's say option 1 and 2 to be checked. How to achieve that.

Comment: Set an initial value for that field of the form?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 form_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[("1", "option 1"),("2", "optiom 2")])
```